# Key Injection using MonkeyRunner in android?

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

> I want to repeat some steps of testing an application. What i think
>   ,first time when i perform the task on that application i will record
>   that steps and after that i want to perform that steps in a loop.
>
> I want to perform both steps recording and playing on the device
>   side.is it possible with monkey runner?
>
> has i study about money Runner from this link 
>   [MonkeyRunner Link](http://antoine-merle.com/introduction-to-the-monkey-runner-tool-2/)
>   i found i need Python 2.7 but i do not
>   have knowledge about python.any help..?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Monkey runner can not record the action.if you want to do this insist, you can dowload 
other automation studio.For example:[SeeTest automation tool](http://experitest.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Two special scripts are written using MonkeyRunner which helps in running automated UI tests. The scripts are as follows:

> monkey_recorder.py
>
> monkey_playback.py

This is exactly what you are looking for. You can record the steps and then create test cases or perform the tasks in a loop.

The links are:
[googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/ics-mr0/monkeyrunner/scripts) or [Github](https://github.com/miracle2k/android-platform_sdk/tree/master/monkeyrunner/scripts)